# tubepress url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, masking, tubepress

Im trying to figure out how to mask all urls on my site to make them "pretty" I would like to replace "tubepress_video" with just "video" and "tubepress_page" to "page" Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example

```
http://mydomain.com/?tubepress_video=m3gRH-hPS9I&tubepress_page=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this: This will only work for the links of this format:
`http://mydomain.com/?tubepress_video=m3gRH-hPS9I&tubepress_page=1`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tubepress\_([^&]+)&tubepress\_([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ?%1&%2 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^tubepress [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^&]+&[^&]+ 
RewriteRule ^ ?tubepress_%1&tubepress_%2 [L]
```